# bootstrap-select: can one use accent insensitive searches?

Tags: bootstrap-select, accent-insensitive

I am using bootstrap-select for a form using `data-live-search` enabled, so that the user can both type the search term and find it in the dropdown. The dropdown list, however, has some terms with accents, like for example:

- León
- Castellón
- Nájera

We'd like to make the search field in bootstrap-select accent-insensitive. Can it be done? I searched through the project's Github and didn't find anything, except for this issue:

https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/767

And it's not clear to me whether it was finally implemented or what.

Answer (score 12):

You were in the right track, you only needed to see the attached tickets. There's an option for that, and was introduced because of that ticket. `liveSearchNormalize` is the option you are looking for, and it can be used in that way when initializing the selectpicker (`liveSearchNormalize: true`), or via data-attribute `data-live-search-normalize="true"`